# FTP request from composer

Tags: php, html, laravel, ftp, composer-php

you know , If you want to request a script from composer you should do that in CMD , I serached a lot about how can I do that in my FTP (host)
without uploading the project again , I mean to connect to the ftp by CMD and requesting a script from composer , thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is not really possible using FTP, what you need is SSH so either you SSH into your machine, or...

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/ssh

in which you can define the common commands and execute it within the application itself e.g.

```
Route::get('composer-update', function(){
    SSH::run([
        'cd /var/www/my-site',
        'composer update',
    ]);    
});
```